# Android | Change the time shown in notification?

Tags: android, notifications

is it possible to change the time shown in notification? the time shown in notification is always the time notification is triggered. can i set custom time? :) Hope there is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`setWhen(long when)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setWhen(long)) to set the timestamp.

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(MainActivity.this);
builder.setTicker("title")
       .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
       .setWhen(time_in_millis);
Notification notification = builder.build();
NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```